# Is it true that if $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Please help me decide if the following statement is true or false:

> If $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx$ converges then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

I tried many counter examples with no luck so I tried to prove it but couldn't pull it off either...

Comment: This is not true, try to construct a function made up of triangles with area $\frac{1}{n^2}$, it does not have a limit, but its integral converges. (Like a saw where its teeth become thinner and thinner).

Comment: [See also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263593/int-1-infty-hx-dx-converges-rightarrow-h-is-bounded-in-1-inf).

Answer (score 1):

See the link in the comments for counterexamples. However, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists then it is zero. To prove this let
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=l$$
and assume $l\neq 0$. Then for some $N$, $f(x)> l-|l|/2$ whenever $x\ge N$. We then have
$$\int_1^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_1^{N}f(x)dx+\int_N^{\infty}f(x)dx>\int_1^{N}f(x)dx+\int_{N}^{\infty}(l+\frac{|l|}{2})dx$$
however the RHS side of the inequality diverges, and thus so must the LHS. This then proves the statement by contrapositive.